# Create Multi Dimensional Array of Objects From Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a handful of arrays one of first names, one of last names, and one of emails. I want to create an object for each index of the arrays.

`firstnames[0], lastnames[0], emails[0]`

would become

`{firstname: value, lastname: value, email: value}`

from which I would take that object and throw it in an array. However currently I am having trouble trying to figure out how to tackle this I can't wrap my brain around it. Hoping someone can help me come up with a clean method of doing this.

Comment: Are your arrays ordered in a way where each index in each `Array` corresponds to the correct match by index?

Comment: Yea more or less. The data comes from a CSV initially, from which has to get reordered to map to specific fields in a DB that they will in the end be plugged into. So index 0 on all three arrays belong together for example

Comment: nnnnn's answer has you covered - also your output example is not a multi-dimensional array. It's an array of objects. Multi-dimensional arrays are arrays that directly contain arrays `[[1,2], [3, 4]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a loop. On each iteration of the loop get the value from each array for the current index. A simple `for` loop would be easiest to understand.

The following uses the [array `.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do this. That iterates over `firstnames` and builds a new array containing whatever values are returned by the function passed to `.map()` as an argument. The advantage of this is that you don't have to manually create an output array and push objects into it, `.map()` does that part for you, and also it avoids creating any working variables in the current scope.

This assumes all arrays are the same length.

```js
var firstnames = ['Annie', 'Ben', 'Chris']
var lastnames = ['Andrews', 'Brown', 'Carmichael']
var emails = ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com']

var output = firstnames.map(function(v, i) {
  return {
    firstname: v,
    lastname: lastnames[i],
    email: emails[i]
  }
})

console.log(output)
```